# How to get user input in java programs in vs code without using public static void main (String[]args)

Tags: java, input

Can anyone please help me how to get user input in java programs in vs code **without** using **public static void main (String [] args)**

I can safely do this thing using **method** call in **BlueJ** ide but couldn't figure out how to do this in vs code or any other ides....

Here is the simple code that I want to run--

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public static void main (int l, int b)
    {
        int area, peri;
        area = l*b;
        peri = 2*(l+b);
        System.out.println("Area = "+area);
        System.out.println("Perimeter = "+peri);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the standard ``public static void main(String[] args)`` method?

Comment: Actually I wanted to know if there are any possibilities of method calling like in BlueJ ide.... in vs code........

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a practical alternative if you are writing a stand-alone command line application in Java.

There are [various libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309250) for command line argument parsing in Java, but (AFAIK) they all require you to write a `public static void main (String [] args)` method .... even if it is just simple boilerplate code.

(This is not true for all kinds of Java application.  For example webapps in a web container, JavaFX applications, or ... applets)

Comment: in BlueJ ide there is a GUI Method call in which we have to pass our arguments (User Input)......it is not a command line input either.......so I wanted to know if there are any such cases/possibilities in vs code or any other such ides.

Comment: Basically, no there isn't.  Most IDEs are designed for developing production code.  This is not something that standard JVMs support.  Hence supporting this in an IDE is counter-productive.  You should be learning how to write programs the *normal* way not the BlueJ way.  ('Cos code that does things the BlueJ way won't work outside of BlueJ.)

Answer (score 1):

```
You cant run a program with out main program. Execution always starts from main program.Your IDE may automatically generate main program, But if you are looking for an alternative way of ( other than command line argument)  getting input  you can use Scanner or any input stream methods 



 import java.util.Scanner
    public class Rectangle
    { 
        public static void main(String arg[])
        {    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
            int l= myObj.nextInt();  // Read user input
            int b=myObj.nextInt(); 
            int area = l*b;
            int peri = 2*(l+b);
            System.out.println("Area = "+area);
            System.out.println("Perimeter = "+peri);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: in BlueJ ide there is a GUI Method call in which we have to pass our arguments (User Input)......it is not a command line input either.......so I wanted to know if there are any such cases/possibilities in vs code or any other such ides.

Answer (score 0):

You can't not do that.

As described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) a java application entry point has to be `public static void main(String[] args)`.

This makes sense. The parameters from the command line arguments are Strings, not matter what. To make `int` out of it, there would be an implicit conversion. Where do you catch parsing errors for that if it happens before it reaches your code?

Comment: in BlueJ ide there is a GUI Method call in which we have to pass our arguments (User Input)......it is not a command line input either.......so I wanted to know if there are any such cases/possibilities in vs code or any other such ides.

Comment: @mastero Sorry I don't know what your IDE exposes here.
It is not the main entry point to a java application. VS code default java support is rather mediocre compared to other more specialized IDEs such as eclipse or IntelliJ.